# Call BoxLayout ID from python file

Tags: python, user-interface, pycharm, kivy, kivy-language

I have a box layout with id : thebox, am finding it difficult getting its id since I want to add widgets to this view dynamically, i have tried calling. self.ids.thebox, which failed, I have also tried, self.ids.parent.thebox, also failed, lastly i tried using ObjectProperty but would get an error as well.

Can someone explain how you would this call using self and id and why that works?

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

#:import utils kivy.utils
#: import Window kivy.core.window.Window

<FlatButton@ButtonBehavior+Label>:
    font_size: 14

<PosWindow>:
    id: main_win
    spacing: 3
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex('#ffffff')
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 80

    #THE BEGINNNING OF THE TOP BAR
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 30

        Label:
            text: 'HEADER POSITION'
            size_hint_x: .6
            bold: True
            color: (1,1,1,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex('#5B2437')
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos


        Label:
            text: 'The Name'
            size_hint_x: .4
            height: 30
            bold: True
            color: (1,1,1,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex('#5B2437')
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos


    #THE BEGINNING OF THE SECOND WAVE FULL
    BoxLayout:
        id: current
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (1,1,1, 1)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        Button:
            text: 'Current Item:'
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: (.06, .32, .32, 1)
            size_hint_x: .4
        Button:
            id: cur_product
            text: 'Default Product'
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: (.06, .4, .4, 1)
        Button:
            id: cur_price
            text: '0.00'
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: (.06, .65, .65, 1)
            size_hint_x: .2
    #THE END OF THE SECOND WAVE FULL



#SEARCH FOR A PRODUCT
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 30
    size_hint_x: 1
    id: searchBox
    spacing: 10
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    TextInput:
        text :'Code | Product Name'
        write_tab: False
        id: qty_inp
        size_hint_x: .7
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: root.change_quantity()

    Button:
        size_hint_x: .3
        id: crud_remove
        text: 'Search'
        on_release: root.searchforproduct()

#END OF SEARCH BOX LAYOUT #WILL NEED TO REMOVE THE WIDGET TO ADD ANEW ONE

#BGN OF MAIN BOX LAYOUT
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size_hint_y: .7
    size_hint_x: 1
    id: searchBox
    spacing: 10
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, .59, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    #THE LIST VIEW BOX
    BoxLayout:
        id: thebox
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: 1
        size_hint_x: .4
        id: searchBox
        spacing: 10

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (1, .59, .45, 1)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos


        Label:
            text: "Hey there we exist"


    #END OF THE LISTVIEW BOX

    #THIS IS THE MIDDLE LINE
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: 1
        size_hint_x: .1
        id: searchBox
        spacing: 10
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (1, .59, .45, 1)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

    #END OF THE MIDDLE LINE

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: 1
        size_hint_x: .5
        id: searchBox
        spacing: 10
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (.57, .89, .45, 1)

            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
```

Comment: Cannot give you a definite answer without seeing the python code, but if you are trying to access the id from within the `App` class, try `self.root.ids.thebox`.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I had 2 IDS one that came after the ID the box and overwrote, a small mistake.